# Non-greedy regex for "variable=value"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

`you will receive a $$product_color product tomorrow <<Purchase_dialog $$product_name=iphone $$product_color= $$product_color=`

What I want to match:

- $$product_name=
- $$product_name=value
- $$product_name=(end of string)

I don't want to match `$$product_color` when there is no equals sign after it.

Here are the regexes that I created:

- `\$\$.+?=(\s|$|.+?\b)` - fails because it matches `$$product_color product tomorrow <<Purchase_dialog $$product_name=iphone`
- `\$\$.+?=[^\s].+?\b` - fails because it doesn't match `$$product_color=`

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to match.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ADC0kV/1

Comment: [Try `\${2}[^$=]+=\S*`](https://regex101.com/r/zQBCMe/2)

Comment: Is that a real sample of the input? If its filled with placeholders, putting an example would be helpful

Comment: @marekful I updated it. https://regex101.com/r/ADC0kV/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex (close to yours)

```
\$\$[^=\s]+?=(\s|$|[^=]+?\b)
```

check here: https://regex101.com/r/nioTAC/1/

Answer (score 1):

the following regex will match even if there are multiple spaces after equal sign.check out the $$pruduct_name. There are multiple spaces preceding the value.

**string :**

`you will receive a $$product_color product tomorrow <<Purchase_dialog` `$$product_name=    iphone $$product_color= 1 $$product_color=`

**regex :**

```
\$\$[\w]*?(?==)=((\s*)(?=[\w]))?[\w]*
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```js
let str='you will receive a $$product_color product tomorrow <<Purchase_dialog $$product_name=iphone $$product_color= $$product_color=';
console.log(str.match(/\$\$[^\s]+?=[^\s]*/g));
```